# Oracle SQL UNION alternative

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm using `ORACLE SQL` (11g), lets assume we have a table named `TRANSMISSIONS` which has field that holds `file sizes`

I want to perform various aggregate functions on various `partitions` let's say for different file sizes. However I want the partitions to be cumulative.
So a `10 KB` file will be both in the `<=500000 bytes` partition and the `<=2000000000` partition. 
So if I had 5 files `<=500000` and 5 files `> 50000 &&  < 2000000000` Then I would have the following reults:

```
   label       | number
---------------|-------
<=500000       | 5
<=2000000000   | 10
```

So basically the initial approach was to do unions like this:

```
SELECT '<=500000' as label,
       COUNT(1) AS numberFiles,
       round(avg(tra.TRA_SIZE)) as averageSize,
       sum(tra.TRA_SIZE) as totalSize
FROM TRANSMISSION tra
where tra.TRA_SIZE <= 500000

UNION

SELECT '<=2000000000' as label,
       COUNT(1) AS numberFiles,
       round(avg(tra.TRA_SIZE)) as averageSize,
       sum(tra.TRA_SIZE) as totalSize
FROM TRANSMISSION tra
where tra.TRA_SIZE <= 2000000000;
```

However if I have several of these `partitions` which I do it will result into a huge unmaintanable query where the only thing that changes basically is the `label` and the `where` clause.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: this could be possible to achieve with multiple columns which you can then pivot to rows. Is this acceptable for you?

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: @micklesh yes sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for cumulative sums.  I think I would go for:

```
SELECT l.label, 
       COUNT(*) AS numberfiles,
       ROUND(AVG(t.tra_size), 2) AS averagesize,
       SUM(t.tra_size) AS totalsize
FROM #TRANSMISSION t JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as ord, '<=500000' as label, 0 as lo, 500000 as hi FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as ord, '<=2000000000' as label, 0 as lo, 2000000000 as hi FROM DUAL
     ) l
     ON t.tra_size BETWEEN l.lo AND l.hi
GROUP BY l.label, l.ord
ORDER BY l.ord;
```

This gives you full flexibility on the ranges that you want -- I am starting at `0`, assuming that is the minimum possible value but the code could be adjusted if this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
WITH limits(n) AS (
SELECT 500000 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL 
SELECT n+500000 FROM limits 
WHERE n < 10000000
)
SELECT
   '<=' || to_char(n,'00000000') AS label,
   round(avg(tra.TRA_SIZE)) as averageSize,
   sum(tra.TRA_SIZE) as totalSize
FROM TRANSMISSION tra
CROSS JOIN limits
WHERE tra.TRA_SIZE <= n
GROUP BY n
ORDER BY n
```

You might want to change the limits, though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you will store the max sizes and corresponding labels in a small table (like the one illustrated below), and you will have an `'ALL'` row for all files (even those bigger than the largest size in your list of max sizes - and including the files where the file size is `null`), you could do something like this:

```
with
  sample_file_data (file_id, file_size) as (
    select 1001,   10000 from dual union all
    select 1083,   50000 from dual union all
    select 1130,  340000 from dual union all
    select 2323, 1435832 from dual union all
    select 3200,    null from dual union all
    select 1039,   34200 from dual union all
    select 4832, 4320933 from dual
  )
, groups (label, max_size) as (
    select '<=   50000',   50000 from dual union all
    select '<=  200000',  200000 from dual union all
    select '<= 1000000', 1000000 from dual union all
    select 'ALL'       ,    null from dual
  )
-- end of simulated input data; query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select label, count(*) as number_
from   sample_file_data join groups on file_size <= max_size or max_size is null
group  by max_size, label
order  by max_size
;

LABEL         NUMBER_
---------- ----------
<=   50000          3
<=  200000          3
<= 1000000          4
ALL                 7
```

(Note - `NUMBER` is an Oracle keyword, not good for a column name; I added an underscore at the end.)

Answer (score 0):

We can write the CASE statement as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN tra_size <= 500000 THEN '<=500000' 
                      WHEN tra_size <= 2000000000 THEN  '<=2000000000'
                      END AS label,
COUNT(1) AS numberfiles,
round(AVG(tra_size)) AS averagesize,
SUM(tra_size) AS totalsize
FROM TRANSMISSION
GROUP BY CASE WHEN tra_size <= 500000 THEN '<=500000' 
                      WHEN tra_size <= 2000000000 THEN  '<=2000000000'
                      END;
```

Comment: Case _expressions_.

Comment: This won't bring cumulative results as case returns immediately when true and ends the statement.
So a size of 100 will match case <= 500000 but not case <= 2000000000